# Spring Security principal.getName() returns object reference rather than the username

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

If I do:

```
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
      username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
} 
else {
      username = principal.toString();
}
```

It should apparently return the username, but in fact it returns the toString() result of my user class

Comment: what is the type of object you get from principal.getName()?

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson my domain User class

Comment: cool, try cast the object you get from getName() to  User class and call the method to get the name.

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson "String cannot be converted to User"

Comment: You _always_ pass and return object references (i.e., pointers) and not objects themselves in Java. This is how it works and should not surprise anyone.

Comment: @LewBloch Yeah I didn't think that would work, any suggestions then? I am a little confused on why it is happening in the first place, everywhere else on the internet seems to suggest it should just return a username

Comment: I am confused, how User class is a String ?

Comment: What does "it is happening" mean? What is happening? What is your definition of it "working" or "not working"? On the face, you describe something working as it ought. Have you read the Java Tutorial?

Comment: Its not, but whats returned from principal.getName() is the user class's toString() output. Would it be bad practise to just override toString to return the username like I want?

Comment: @LewBloch In every example I have seen, using some method to get the current user in spring security returns a username that you can use to search your database etc. However when I do it, it returns to toString() output for my user class

Comment: All right. That's nice. If you want help with that then perhaps you should show us your code. I don't even know what "returns to toString() output for my user class" means. Show us your code. Otherwise, well, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Username can be achieved by following below code

```
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am using, but it returns the toString() result of my user class.